# Calling a method defined in parameter as fallback

Tags: php

I'm having doubts as the best way to approach this:

What I want to do is to be able to call a method that will first verify if the data I need is on cache, then if not available execute a fallback method that I define as a parameter on the original method.

```
public function index() {
    $data['some_cache'] = $this->get_cache('cache_key', $this->get_list_something('entered fallback method'));
}

public function get_cache($key, $fallback_function) {
    $data = FALSE;
    if ( ! empty($key)) {
        $data = $this->cache($key);
        if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $fallback_function;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

public function cache($key) {
    // try to find something on cache list (either memory cache / file cache) I just return FALSE to fail on purpose
    return FALSE;
}

public function get_list_something($param) {
    return $param;
}
```

I could send the method name as a string, and the parameters as an array, then call it using call_user_func_array (leading to changes on get_cache method).

So my question boils down to this: Is this good practice? What issues can I encounter doing this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this, user_call_method() or user_call_function()

I assumed you are using a class method here, and not regular functions based on the usage of $this

so try this out and maybe you will get some ideas from it.

```
<?php

  class test {

    public function index() {
      $data['some_cache'] = $this->get_cache('cache_key', 'get_list_something','test','test2');
      return $data['some_cache'];
    }

    public function get_cache($key, $fallback_function) {
      $data = FALSE;
      if ( ! empty($key)) {
        $data = $this->cache($key);
        $args = func_get_args(); // Dynamically Pass Arguments optional    
        unset($args[0]); unset($args[1]); // Unset the cach_key, and method name get_list_something   
        if ($data==false) {
          $data = @call_user_method($fallback_function,$this,$args);
        }
      }

      return $data;
    }

    public function cache($key) {
      $flag = false;
      $words = ($flag)?'true':'false';
      echo 'cache returning <b>'.$words.'</b>, testing <b>fallback_function</b><br>'; 
      return $flag;
    }

    public function get_list_something(&$args) { 
      $params = implode(',',$args);  
      echo 'running <b>fallback_function</b><br>';
      return $params;
    }

  }

  $test = new test();
  echo $test->index();

?>
```

Comment: Not confortable using call_user_method when it has been deprecated since PHP 4.1. But I could always use the alternatives provided.

Comment: yes that is true it is depreciated, let me see if i can rework it to something else.